# Where is "gotRemoteDescription" called?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, es6-promise

Update:

### It is indeed not called at all!

I am learning WebRTC and there is a good example (https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/blob/master/s/webrtc-simple-datachannel/main.js).

Overall the code is well written. But what a hard part I cannot get is: 
where is the function `gotRemoteDescription` called in that code?

`gotRemoteDescription` only appears once in the the file. So I cannot find the caller.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Are you sure that it is called at all?

Comment: I guess `gotRemoteDescription` is just a method author forgot to use, the 2 lines written 10 lines above it, does the same job making it redundant.

Comment: What @mido22 says. Looks like this code got converted to use the promise-version of the API, which is more concise, and one of the advantages is that one doesn't need 100 callbacks any longer get things done.